# How to determine whether http proxy server causes latency

Tags: networking

Is there an equivalent of the 'traceroute' command which shows network latencies and hops for the path of an HTTP request rather than the ICMP routing? The reason I ask is that we suspect an http proxy server is the source of high network latencies for a particular set of application users and would like to have a simple test to determine whether it is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

May be, you can use hping.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I took a quick look at the hping documentation, but nothing jumped out in terms of how to utilize it to generate a trace for http routing. Any tips for accomplishing this?